# Suppose G is a connected planar simple graph with $e$ edges and $v$ vertices with no cycles of length 4 or less...

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

Suppose G is a connected planar simple graph with $e$ edges and $v$ vertices with
no cycles of length 4 or less.

Prove  that (For $ v ≥ 4$):
$$e ≤ {\frac{5}{3}}v - {\frac{10}{3}}$$

-I have a basic understanding of planar graphs based off of our lecture in class. I understand that planar means it can be drawn on a single plane without any edges crossing and I know that since it's a connected graph it has one component, and I know that since it is a simple graph it does not contain loops or multi-edges. Although I don't understand how to tie this in with a proof such as this, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use Euler's formula and double-count the number of pairs $(e,f)$ such that $e$ is an edge of the face $f$.

Answer (score 1):

The following theorem is well known in graph theory (see theorem 6.10 in http://compalg.inf.elte.hu/~tony/Oktatas/TDK/FINAL/Chap%206.PDF):

For a connected simple planar graph with $v$ vertices and $e$ edges, and girth $g$, we have 
$$e\leq \frac{g}{g-2}(v-2)$$

Note the girth $g$ is the length  of the smallest cycle.

In our case $g=5$, thus $$e\leq \frac{5}{3}(v-2)$$

Comment: This looks good,although in our question is states that this must be less than or equal to the number of edges, where do we get this number from and how do we know that the edges will always be less than it when v is greater than or equal to 4?

Comment: @D.Peterson I have not completely understand the problem that you are talking about. Could you please be more specific about it?

Comment: I understand the theorem that you presented. But I don't see how to apply this specifically to the $v\ge4$ case as the question states. Furthermore, do you apply a real number in as $e$ or just leave it as a variable to represent any # of edges w/ the 4 vertices.

Comment: @D.Peterson The result apply to all graphs with girth of least 5. Then it's true for all graphs with $v\geq 5$ (Or if they do not have cycles, then they will be trees and it will be also true " in tree $e\leq v-1$ "). Note that the since the smallest cycle is of length 5, then the result is obvious for $v=4$. Thus the above result  is true for $v\geq 4$. On the other hand, $e$ is the number of edges of any planar graph with girth at least 5.

Answer (score 1):

The sum of the degree of the regions in the graph will be $2e$ as each edge contributes to 2 regions. But again, we have no circuits of length $4$ or less. So each region has degree $\geq 5$. So, $2e \geq 5f \implies \frac{2}{5}e \geq f$.

Now, apply the Euler's formula which states $v-e+f=2\implies e-v+2=f \implies e-v+2 \leq \frac{2}{5}e \implies e \leq \frac{5}{3}v - \frac{10}{3}$.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are stuck at why $5$ and $g$ in the other 2 answers by tomriddle99 and M.Badaoui. Here I show the reasons behind that.

---

For any edge, it contributes 1 (in one cycle) or 2 (not in one cycle) to the degree of the region it is inside.

Then when $v=4$, it may be $C_4$ (cycle-4) which has degree 4, $C_3$ with one edge with degree 5, $C_2$ with 2 edges (but $C_2$ is excluded by not allowing the multi-edge), $C_1$ with 3 edges (excluded by not allowing the loop) or $C_0$ with 4 edges with degree 8.

For $v=1\sim 3$, the above process can also be applied although you stated $v\ge 4$.

Since "no cycles of length 4 or **less**", so we can only $v=5$ which has the least degree 5 when $C_5$. This is what the reference chapter by M.Badaoui says:

> As g is the length of the **smallest cycle** in G,
> therefore g is the **smallest degree** of a region.